# Tengo un problema en como codificar los metodos para que se cargue mi combobox dependiente

Tags: mysql, c#, combobox

[image: Imgen]

Hola a todos :D. Necesito que el `Combobox` anidado me muestre en la pantalla de "editar producto" los nombres correspondientes de lo que se ingresó anteriormente para así poder editar la categoría, área y sección... En otras palabras necesito capturar y visualizar en el `Combobox` lo que se ingresó... Puedo mostrar todo el contenido desde la base de datos, todo funciona bien, pero ¿como lo haría para capturar lo que seleccionó el usuario y al mismo tiempo poder editarlo???

---

Aquí llamo al procedimiento almacenado de cada tabla (Categoria, Área,Sección).

```
         public List<EN_Categoria> ObtenerCategorias()
         {
         List<EN_Categoria> ListaCategorias = new List<EN_Categoria>();
         MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection();
         cn.ConnectionString = Conectar();
         {
             MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_listar_todas_categorias", cn);
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             cmd.CommandTimeout = 20;
             cn.Open();
             
             MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

             while (dr.Read())
                 
             {
                 ListaCategorias.Add(new EN_Categoria

                 {

                     Id_categoria = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id_Cat"]),
                     Nombre_categoria = Convert.ToString(dr["Categoria"].ToString())

                 } );
                 
             }
             dr.Close();
             
         }
         return ListaCategorias;
     }


     public List<EN_Area> ObtenerAreas(int Id_Cat)
     {
         List<EN_Area> ListaAreas = new List<EN_Area>();
         MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection();
         cn.ConnectionString = Conectar();
         {
             MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_Listar_Areas", cn);
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_Id_Cat", Id_Cat);
             cmd.CommandTimeout = 20;
             cn.Open();

             MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

             while (dr.Read())

             {
                 ListaAreas.Add(new EN_Area

                 {

                     Id_area = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id_Area"]),
                     Nombre_area = Convert.ToString(dr["Area"].ToString())

                 });

             }
             dr.Close();
             
         }
         return ListaAreas;
     }



     public List<EN_Seccion> ObtenerSeccion(int Id_Area)
     {
         List<EN_Seccion> ListaSecciones = new List<EN_Seccion>();
         MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection();
         cn.ConnectionString = Conectar();
         {
             MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_Listar_Secciones", cn);
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_Id_Area", Id_Area);
             cmd.CommandTimeout = 20;
             cn.Open();

             MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

             while (dr.Read())

             {
                 ListaSecciones.Add(new EN_Seccion

                 {

                     Id_seccion = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id_Seccion"]),
                     Nombre_seccion = Convert.ToString(dr["Seccion"].ToString())

                 });

             }
             dr.Close();
             
         }
         return ListaSecciones;
     }
```

Comment: No se si te entiendo bien. Lo normal es que te suscribas al evento `SelectedIndexChanged` del combobox Categoria por ejemplo, y ahi accedas a la propiedad `SelectedItem` de categoria  y llamar a ObtenerArea con el id del SelectedItem de Categoría. No se si es eso lo que necesitabas

Comment: Solo quiero que me muestre lo que yo seleccioné anteriormente. En el momento que ingresé el combobox anidado yo ingresé los datos correspondientes, pero al momento de llamar al boton editar de mi listview me carga la lista completa, sin el dato correspondiente.